# Is it possible to have a valid backupset with null position?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup, restore

In database restore process I need to rely on `position` column exists in `backupset` record to restore the latest backupset.

[Restore the latest backup on the database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34508/restore-the-latest-backup-on-the-database)

I noticed sometimes `position` is null. What does cause this? In msdn it's said that `Position` can be null, but no more explanation on under what condition it can happen.
Does it mean the backup file is corrupted?
Any idea?

Thanks.